upper bound on expectation of reciprocal of square root of bounded random variable
Let $X$ be a random variable satisfying $a \le X \le b$. I know $\mu_x = E[X]$. I want to upper bound $E[1/\sqrt{X}]$ in terms of $\mu_X$. I don't know $Var[X]$.
Jensen's inequality doesn't help. There is a trivial upper bound, i.e. $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}$. I want to do better than that since I know $\mu_X$. Any help most appreciated.

Can you solve any simple cases, to get intuition?  What about two weighted delta distributions centered on $a$ and $b$?
